# Show custom payment option value at backed order detail page and invoice

Tags: magento-1.8

I have created some custom options for payment. Like this article has suggested.

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/28/magento-create-custom-payment-method/

Now I want to show these custom column values to back-end order detail page and at invoice too.

Please guide How can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your payment method you can assign an Info form block with setting (I took the Purchaseorder method as an example):

```
protected $_infoBlockType = 'payment/info_purchaseorder';
```

In this block you can assign the template file you want to use (see Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Purchaseorder for complete code):

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('payment/info/purchaseorder.phtml');
    }
```

And in this template file you can add info you want to dispay (the fields you added during the checkout):

```
<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
    <li>
        <label for="po_number" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Purchase Order Number') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="po_number" name="payment[po_number]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Purchase Order Number') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getInfoData('po_number')) ?>" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This will display the information entered at checkout in the order detail page.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am already using this. And this code show value for front-end. And I am asking for back-end. I want to show these options to back-end

Comment: If you place your template file in the adminhtml/.... design directory this should also show up on your backend.